# How to set a relative web path in a HTML page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web

I am building a website. I have many folders. The highest layer is called FOLDER1. I have two folders in FOLDER1. They are FOLDER2A, and FOLDER2B. Inside FOLDER2B, there is a html file. I need to use a picture "DOG" in FOLDER1 in that html. If I don't want to use absolute path like http://abc.com/FOLDER1/DOG.jpg as a path, how I can use a relative path like /Folder1/DOG.jpg <=== I know that this is wrong

Thanks

Comment: /Folde1/DOG.jpg should work, as the first / will start from the root of the application. You could also use ../DOG.jpg.

Comment: You are right . The ../ work. If you want, you can put your comment as answer, I will mark it as correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

../DOG.jpg   unless I'm missing something here.  .. means up one folder. ../../ means up two, etc. To access an image in FOLDER2A from FOLDER2B  ../FOLDER2A/CAT.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to files in the parent directory using `../`, i.e. `../DOG.jpg` will refer to DOG.jpg in FOLDER1 if referred to from inside FOLDER2A or FOLDER2B.